# Create a 2D trail in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, trail-renderer

I would like to make a trail for a pixelated snake such as this one :

[image]

As you can see, the cross simply repeats itself to create the snake. In Unity I have messed around with Trail Renderer, tried everything to import the cross as a texture / sprite, then created all sorts of materials for it, but it just won't work the same way.

How can I achieve this effect please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that the effect which you desire won't be able to achieve through Trail renderer.
I had once accidentally achieved it while playing with multiple cameras.
What you need is to stop the camera from clearing the render buffer before drawing a new frame. So that the cross at last position remains as is and the new cross gets drawn on top of it . This doesn't affects the draw calls or performance, as it is just refraining the buffer from clearing.
You need to play around with Clear Flags settings for camera , and set it to don't clear.

Comment: Well that does it, but it sort of creates the effect for everything rendered by the camera. What if I wanted just that specific cross, while other things in the scene don't leave behind such a trail?

Comment: You could only allow the second camera to display the layer containing your cross pattern.

Comment: Yes savlon is right , assign the object for which you want the effect to take place to a different layer and select that layer in the camera's culling option.

Answer (score 0):

ONE method could be using an object with a particle system. Manage the particle system the right way , controlling it by script, spamming ONE particle based on object moviments. Use the cross ad particle texture..